# BCP: Unable to resolve column level collations

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Running this:

```
bcp MyDb.dbo.uvwMyView out "c:\Test.txt" -SMyServer -T -c
```

I get this error:

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Unable to resolve column level collations
```

Searching google finds many possible solutions, none of which work for me or have worked for any of the people they were proposed for.  As with other cases posted online, the view causes no problems when I select from it in Management Studio and the results look normal (and have no special characters, I checked).  The one text column in the results has collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`.  I have tried several options to bcp with no effect: -w, -CRAW, -COEM, -C850, -C437.

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the view and recreating it fixed the problem.  Unfortunately this doesn't explain how the problem happened in the first place, or how to prevent it in the future.  This isn't a satisfying solution, so if anyone knows a better answer, I'm still very interested in hearing it.

Comment: It's been 11 years now, and this problem never happened again.  How strange.

Comment: I'm seeing it right now, but on tables not views.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select * from database_name.dbo.table_name" queryout      H:\Tempfile_DTU_proc\test1.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername

exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

- You may try to remote connect to the server and run the bcp without the -s option from there.
- If the server collation is different from the database or column collation, try to create the format file and explicitly specify it in the bcp.

Comment: That might not be easy for me, but I might try that, and it might provide useful info (though I doubt it).  Unfortunately I won't be able to run the process like that in production no matter what, so it won't help me in the long run, unless it somehow helps track down the real source of the problem.

Comment: Good idea with the format file, but unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: What does it say for column format (see the xml) when you run this:

bcp MyDB.dbo.uvwMyView format null -f c:\FMT_01.xml -x -c -T -t

Comment: Annoyingly enough, I get the same error message.  That is to say, I can't run the statement you mention.  The way I made the format file I used in my previous test was to use an existing format file on a view that is the exact same format (selects from the same tables) and doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already answered but I'll add my 2 cents...
I ran into this today, I had add a PRINT @VarableName and in researching I found this:

[From MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/274313/bcp-error-unable-to-resolve-column-level-collations)

Removing the PRINT fixed my problem.

Comment: Interesting, and thanks for adding this, but it wasn't the problem I had.  I didn't have any PRINT statements.

Answer (score 0):

I was using SQL 2005 tools against a SQL 2008 R2 database, and I got the same error when using `datetimeoffset` fields.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and found a different solution.  Due to a configuration mistake, the server name was not supplied to the BCP command.  For sake of redundancy and documentation, this the message: "The error SQLState = S1  000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations  BCP copy out failed"

Change the a null server value specified in the Server (-S) parameter to the correct server name.